# Upload files via ajax when added to a multiple file input (WordPress)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, upload

I'm trying to upload files from a multiple file upload HTML input via ajax on a WordPress site but I keep getting a 400 error and I'm not sure why.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){

  file_data = $(this).prop('files');
  form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');
  form_data.append('nonce', $('#file_upload_nonce').val());

  $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: form_data,
      success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
  });
    
});
```

And here's my PHP:

```
function file_upload(){
  // Check the nonce first
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'file_upload' ) ) {
    echo 'Security validation failed.';
  } else {
    $upload = wp_upload_bits($_FILES["file"]["name"], null, file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]));
  }
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_file_upload','file_upload');
```

Where am I going wrong here?

---

**EDIT**

Based on CBroe's comment I realised that this wasn't set up to handle multiple files properly so, based on [this tutorial](https://carlofontanos.com/ajax-multi-file-upload-in-wordpress-front-end/), I tried changing my code as per below.

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(){

  var fd = new FormData();
  var files_data = $(this); // The <input type="file" /> field

  // Loop through each data and create an array file[] containing our files data.
  $.each($(files_data), function(i, obj) {
      $.each(obj.files,function(j,file){
          fd.append('files[' + j + ']', file);
      })
  });

  fd.append('action', 'file_upload');

  fd.append('nonce', $('#file_upload_nonce').val());

  fd.append('application_id', $(this).closest('.application_question').attr('data-application-id'));

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
  });

});
```

PHP:

```
function file_upload(){
  // Check the nonce first
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'file_upload' ) ) {
    echo 'Security validation failed.';
  } else {

    $application_id = $_POST['application_id'];

    foreach ( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name ) {

      move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], '/wp-content/supporting-evidence/' . $application_id . '/' . $_FILES["files"]["name"][$f] );

    }

  }
  wp_die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_file_upload','file_upload');
```

This still returns a 400 error, but I feel like I'm getting closer to what I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you can use `FormData.append` to just append a whole `files` collection, you'll need to pick one specific file entry out of that. (Or add them in a loop, if you wanted to upload multiple files in one single request here? But I guess that is probably not what you wanted, in combination with a change handler on the file input field that makes rather little sense, plus your server-side code appears to only handle one single file anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment CBroe. I based this code on a tutorial I found but yes, I'm trying to upload multiple files one way or another. If you know of a better approach then I'm all ears :)

Comment: You could supply the `form` as an argument to `FormData` and then append the `action` and `nonce`

Comment: I've tried that approach but I'm still getting the 400 error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here some basic examples so please check.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on('change','input[type="file"]',function(e){
        var files = event.target.files;
        // file_data = jQuery(this).prop('files');
        var form_data = new FormData();
        for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            form_data.append(files[i].name, files[i])
        }
        form_data.append('action', 'file_upload');
        form_data.append('security', "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'file_upload' ); ?>");

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        
    });
});

PHP:

function file_upload(){
      // Check the nonce first
      if ( ! isset( $_POST['security'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['security'], 'file_upload' ) ) {
        echo 'Security validation failed.';
      } else {
        if( !empty($_FILES) ){
            foreach( $_FILES as $file_key => $get_files){
                
                $upload = wp_upload_bits($get_files["name"], null, file_get_contents($get_files["tmp_name"]));
                // print_r($upload);
            }
            echo "Sucess";
        }else{
            echo "Please select files.";
        }
      }
      wp_die();
    }
    add_action('wp_ajax_file_upload','file_upload');
```

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to get it working with this code but I would like to upload them to a custom directory such as `/wp-content/supporting-evidence/XX(application ID)/filename.ext` - how would I go about doing that?

Comment: For simplicity, the application ID directory isn't necessarily needed.

Comment: Don't worry, I've got it working, thanks all the same :)

Comment: You need to use "move_uploaded_file()" if you want to upload in custom directory :)

And please up this answer so might be this answer useful for other user